# Count the number of contacts in each Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, contact, soap, automation

I have 2 BUs in the Marketing Cloud and each has its own contacts.

My issue is that my client wants to retrieve the number of contacts in each BUs, because each BU has its own budget and can only proportion the budget base on the contacts they sent.

To my knowledge, there aren't any tools from Marketing Cloud that help to achieve this. Does anyone know any workaround methods to help me achieve this?

I was thinking of using the SOAP/REST API to fetch all the Data extensions > Retrieve contacts in each of those DE > Merge them and remove the duplication.

Not sure if this is a good/feasible idea? Has anyone ever built this kind of solution or even better, had a solution without dealing with the API calls?

Comment: contacts are all "owned" by the EID

Comment: @EazyE Hi, what is the EID here if I may ask?

Comment: EID = top level MID

Comment: I went to each BU (MID), and generate the report in Analytics > Report. But the question was: the billing contacts generated for each BU were 352 and 1, which is a bit weird, thus I wasn't sure if it's the correct way to fetch the billing contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Reports, Contacts, then to Contact Counts which will display the total billable count of Contacts in your account.

Comment: Hi, I generate the report but the result returned 0, but the actual results are more than that.

Comment: this report runs at the EID